# Laravel Vapor and Lavavel Excel queued imports failing. due to temp storage not existing Laravel 8 Vapor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel, laravel-vapor

When I am trying to run an import that implements chunk reading and queues I am receiving the following error from the vapor queue;

```
ErrorException: touch(): Unable to create file /tmp/storage/framework/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-7IEEz0rP7NORtp7N4NeOxuH0hlbM9JPR.csv because No such file or directory in /var/task/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Files/RemoteTemporaryFile.php:97
```

Documentation On Laravel Excel says to set these value in config/excel.php

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html#multi-server-setup

```
'temporary_files' => [
        'local_path'          => storage_path('framework/laravel-excel'),        
        'remote_disk'         => 's3',       
        'force_resync_remote' => true,
```

My vapor yml file has the following storage set up all working fine with correct env values. for vapor and local development

```
storage: **correct bucket name**
```

Has anyone managed to get Queued imports working with Laravel Excel and Vapor, and if so how did you manage it? the documentation doesn't really explain what values I should use

Answer (score 8):

Try to set `local_path` to the tmp dir in the config file

```
<?php

return [
    'temporary_files' => [
        'local_path' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        ...
    ],
];
```